# Why doesnt Pip have compiled files rather than wheels?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, compilation, pip

While installing some of the packages, we need to downloads the wheel file (via pip) and then compile using Microsoft tools in our system. Why doesn't pip have the compiled files in their server so that we could skip installing the Microsoft Tools?

Comment: Do you mean some specific packages?

Comment: Because not everyone uses Windows?

Comment: @DYZ doesnt linux require compilation?

Comment: A wheel can contain compiled files. It is just a container, basically a zip file. You could install a module on different operating systems by having different wheels with different binaries for the same module.

Comment: If it's a _wheel_ then it's either already compiled or doesn't need compilation at all. Or am I missing the point of the question?

Comment: answer the correct one and i'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a wheel then it's either already compiled or doesn't need compilation at all.

- https://docs.python.org/3/distributing/index.html?highlight=wheel#key-terms
- https://packaging.python.org/glossary/#term-wheel
- https://packaging.python.org/discussions/wheel-vs-egg/
- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/